# Error en PL/SQL con un procedimiento con loops

Tags: oracle, plsql, apex

1

Intento resolver la siguiente cuestión:

Pedir al Usuario la nacionalidad, y que muestre los clientes con esa nacionalidad, para ello he usado un bloque anónimo y un procedimiento que es el siguiente:

Procedimiento:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_emplea IS SELECT SALARY, DEPARTMENT_ID
        FROM EMPLOYEES 
        WHERE salary IS NOT NULL;
    vr_emplea c_emplea%ROWTYPE;
    v_department_name DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
    v_incremento EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
    v_salary_actual EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
    v_salary_resto EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
   
BEGIN
    v_department_name := 'Marketing';
    OPEN c_emplea;
    FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea.department_name;
    WHILE c_emplea%FOUND LOOP
        if DEPARTMENTS.department_name = v_department_name THEN
            v_incremento := SALARY + 0.20;
            SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME 
            INTO v_department_name 
            FROM DEPARTMENTS
            WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = vr_emplea.DEPARTMENT_ID;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El promedio del salario actual de los empleados de' ||  v_department_name || 'es ' || v_salary_actual  || 'y con el incremento es: ' || v_incremento );
             END IF;
             FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea;
    END LOOP;
    BEGIN
       v_department_name := 'Sales';
    OPEN c_emplea;
    FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea;
    WHILE c_emplea%FOUND LOOP
        if DEPARTMENTS.department_name = v_department_name THEN
            v_incremento := SALARY + 0.15;
            SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME 
            INTO v_department_name 
            FROM DEPARTMENTS
            WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = vr_emplea.DEPARTMENT_ID;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El promedio del salario actual de los empleados de' ||  v_department_name || 'es ' || v_salary_actual  || 'y con el incremento es: ' || v_incremento );
        END IF;
        FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea;
    END LOOP;
    BEGIN
    OPEN c_emplea;
    FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea;
    WHILE c_emplea%FOUND LOOP
        if DEMPARTMENTS.department_name = v_department_name THEN
            v_salary_resto := SALARY + 0.5;
            SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME 
            INTO v_department_name 
            FROM DEPARTMENTS
            WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = vr_emplea.DEPARTMENT_ID;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'las demás áreas reciben un aumento de' || v_salary_resto );
        END IF;
        FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea.department_id;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_emplea;
END;
```

Este bloque me da el siguiente error:

ORA-06550: línea 57, columna 0:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "end-of-file" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:

( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
 
 << continue close current delete fetch lock
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query
json_object json_array

ORA-06512: en "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", línea 581

ORA-06512: en "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", línea 1658

ORA-06512: en "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", línea 567

ORA-06512: en "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", línea 2127

Answer (score 2):

Este error no es precisamente relacionado a Oracle APEX, sino al código PL/SQL que has construido.

En el código revisa que tienes dos sentencias BEGIN pero no se encuentra la sentencia END que termine el bloque de código.

Como recomendación, incluye siempre una sección de excepciones.

De acuerdo al requerimiento que tengas, posiciona la sentencia END donde corresponda, por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_emplea IS SELECT SALARY, DEPARTMENT_ID
        FROM EMPLOYEES 
        WHERE salary IS NOT NULL;
    vr_emplea c_emplea%ROWTYPE;
    v_department_name DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
    v_incremento EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
    v_salary_actual EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
    v_salary_resto EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
   
BEGIN
    v_department_name := 'Marketing';
    OPEN c_emplea;
    FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea.department_name;
    WHILE c_emplea%FOUND LOOP
        if DEPARTMENTS.department_name = v_department_name THEN
            v_incremento := SALARY + 0.20;
            SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME 
            INTO v_department_name 
            FROM DEPARTMENTS
            WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = vr_emplea.DEPARTMENT_ID;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El promedio del salario actual de los empleados de' ||  v_department_name || 'es ' || v_salary_actual  || 'y con el incremento es: ' || v_incremento );
             END IF;
             FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea;
    END LOOP;
    BEGIN
       v_department_name := 'Sales';
    OPEN c_emplea;
    FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea;
    WHILE c_emplea%FOUND LOOP
        if DEPARTMENTS.department_name = v_department_name THEN
            v_incremento := SALARY + 0.15;
            SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME 
            INTO v_department_name 
            FROM DEPARTMENTS
            WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = vr_emplea.DEPARTMENT_ID;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El promedio del salario actual de los empleados de' ||  v_department_name || 'es ' || v_salary_actual  || 'y con el incremento es: ' || v_incremento );
        END IF;
        FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea;
    END LOOP;
    **END;**
    BEGIN
    OPEN c_emplea;
    FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea;
    WHILE c_emplea%FOUND LOOP
        if DEMPARTMENTS.department_name = v_department_name THEN
            v_salary_resto := SALARY + 0.5;
            SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME 
            INTO v_department_name 
            FROM DEPARTMENTS
            WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = vr_emplea.DEPARTMENT_ID;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'las demás áreas reciben un aumento de' || v_salary_resto );
        END IF;
        FETCH c_emplea INTO vr_emplea.department_id;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_emplea;
  **END;**
END;
```